# Append string before and after

Tags: string, bash, sed

How could I use bash or sed to put string before and after a match? There are 4 spaces before and \n after the pattern.

Input:

```
Irrelevant text
    line of code
Irrelevant text
```

Output

```
Irrelevant text
    {code}line of code{code}
Irrelevant text
```

I tried

```
CONTENT=$(while read -r line;
do     line=${line//'    '/'    {code}'};
line=${line//\n/'{code}'};     
echo $line; done < testfile)
```

but it is not producing output i want.

Edit: How would I do it if I even wanted to append a different string before and different string after the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using 'sed' on the whole file.

```
sed -e 's/    \(.*\)$/    {code}\1{code}/'
```

The `s` operator will select the text after the spaces in group #1, and will then replace wrapped the captured group (`\1`) with `{code}`.

Using `sed` is significantly more efficient than using bash on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: Would you explain the (.*\)$  please?